# How to add an event to UIImageView subclass the way it would be in IB

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uiimageview, subclass

I'm tired that UIButton's image is too complicated to customize. And it's long to create tappable UIImageView. Than i want to create own mixed element of UIImage and UIButton. It would let to create custom animation, touch areas and lot more.

I decided to take a UIImageView and add a gesture or a button to it to detect touches. But i need to have a TouchUpInside or just touch event to easily connect it in IB. Look at the code, what is already written:

```
class ClickableImageView: UIImageView {
    let embeddedButton = UIButton()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setup()
    }

    fileprivate func setup() {
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        sv(embeddedButton)
        embeddedButton.fillContainer()
        embeddedButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPress), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc fileprivate func didPress() {
        embeddedButton.preventRepeatedPresses()


    }
}
```

[image]

I did the same with the UIButton subclassing and it works, but it not showing the image in IB, so it confuse the developer.

The last problem to solve is how to add the event?

Answer (score 0):

UIButton image can be easily resized by giving distance from (top,left,bottom and right) of the UIButton like below.

```
yourButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 50, 10, 95)
```

If you are looking for adding an event to the UIImageView, do the following,

```
yourImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let tapImage = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(myFunction(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
yourImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapImage)
```

Then handle your method,

```
@objc func myFunction(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
//do something here
}
```